# Combine fields – images and text

Tags: entities, media, nodes

I want to have content type tutorial, with descriptions step by step, consisting of text paragraphs and pictures as an explanation (like clickable thumbnails or just picture).

I know how to add field like text text and image, add set a possibility of make it's number unlimited. But how allow user to arrange order of pictures and text?

Example:

TITLE of PAGE

PARAGRAPH 1

PICTURE 1

PARAGRAPH 2

PICTURE 2

PICTURE 3

PARAGRAPH 3

PARAGRAPH 4

Comment: Maybe I'm being cynical, but "I want to have tutorial, with descriptions step by step" sounds just like "can somebody do my job because I don't want to search and learn Drupal". If you did try to find a solution, tell us what you found, explain why that didn't (completely) solve your problem, and ask more specific questions.

Comment: I'm not english native, apologies if it sounds like "demand". Basically - it might be just a one-word tip what I was looking for, not an instruction. I have some drupal experience but I don't know if it requires to look for some module or it's just a superposition of existing modules and fields.

Comment: I see plenty of modules used for galleries and image handling but I think it should be possible to done just with fields, some dragdrop table to set order of their appearance. That's why I've posted this question - to hear "use X module" or "you just need to set content type fields" or "you need to use views".

Comment: OK, I understand. I don't know of a solution that will allow you to arrange multiple field values in an arbitrary order. I hope someone else does.

Comment: @marcvangend think you completely misunderstood the context of the phrase "step by step". OP was describing what he wanted to do, which is a tutorial content type with field collections and each field is a step of the tutorial, but you thought OP's asking for step-by-step instructions on how to implement it.

Comment: I am glad you caught that, I didn't see where we both misunderstood. That's right, "tutorial step-by-step" which doesn't imply anyone telling what to do with details :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [field collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) it allow you to make a subform inside a form so you can add more than subform and arrange them

Answer (score 3):

[Draggable Views](http://drupal.org/project/draggableviews) does exactly that : ordering contents arbitrarily by hand. If you dare, you can even use [this](http://drupal.org/project/sgrid), which is more lightweight but probably much less flexible and stable. I can tell, I wrote it ...

Comment: Ok, I see it's closer to my needs. But let me ask - is it possible to use this with Views or at least avoiding creation of nodes for each "step" ? I'd rather see this done by reorganizing order of fields, not nodes in Views.

Comment: @wtk try Field Collection module suggested by Ahmed, that module does what you're describing. Just set the number of values of your Field collection field to Unlimited. And you'll have a button that says "Add new" and everytime you click that button you get new "step" added on to your form.

Comment: It's a Views plugin, so it's for arranging nodes. To rearrange fields, you could use just Fields UI and some JQuery to display alternatively the fields related to each step. But the problem with a Content Type for your purpose is that you'll have to assume each tutorial will have the same structure, which doesn't seem to fit your needs, if I understood them correctly.

Comment: ok, it looks like Field Collection is indeed that could realize my use case but for now I stumble upon error that crashes site - it's being discussed on drupal.org, I hope they gonna fix it because it's promissing. Thank you all.